# Cant boot into Windows 8 through grub2 menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I installed kubuntu15.04 alongside windows8.1 and it worked perfectly for some days...but it stopped showing grub menu so I installed EasyBCD software and I think I messed up with its settings AND NOW I CANT BOOT INTO WINDOWS8.1(it shows grub2 menu and Kubuntu works fine) I installed boot-reapir and it gave me this url:

( [1]: http://paste2.org/KMmKBHZ5)

I know my windows is not gone but when I boot into windows it shows cant boot into windows and UEI file not found etc.

When windows is selected from grub It shows:

```
FILE:\BCD
Status:0x00000098
Info:The boot configuration data file doesn't contain any OS.
```

please help me
thank you.

Comment: what is the output of the command `sudo os-prober`

Comment: /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi

Comment: If you have a Windows installation CD, perhaps you could do an automated repair. That might leave Ubuntu unable to boot, but you can try different settings with EasyBCD to get it working again. However, if you have an OEM CD, be careful, as OEM disks tend to wipe your system, rather than giving you the tools to fix the problem in a non-invasive way.

Comment: I dont have and backup CD,but I had inbuilt recovery partition in windows..I dont know how to use it....but my windows is not gone,I just messed up the settings..Damn EasyBCD

Comment: Try going [HERE](https://neosmart.net/blog/windows-recovery-discs/), and downloading one of NeoSmart's disks. IDK if Kubuntu comes with any disk burning programs, but Ubuntu has one called Brasero. If Kubuntu doesn't come with one, you could install Brasero manually.

Comment: It is Paid-_-@TSJNachos117

Comment: D'oh! I should have noticed that. Well there are instructions on how to make a recovery CD on Google. I guess your best bet is to borrow a Windows computer from a friend and make a boot disk (or, you could borrow a disk from a freind, whichever).

Comment: You can create a [windows rescue disk](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-create-a-windows-8-recovery-disk/) or probably try to use one of [these](http://www.gfi.com/blog/top-5-free-rescue-discs-for-your-sys-admin-toolkit/) rescue disks which are available free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found answer.....Solved perfectly:
I use HP so I had recovery partition ,I booted into windows recovery(F11 in my case).
Then went to Repair your computer...this should fix my problem But it couldn't find anything.So here is my solution:

1. go to troubleshoot in recovery menu.
2. Click Advanced options in Troubleshoot screen.
3. Click on command Prompt.
4. Type these following commands and hit enter after each line of command:

   ```
   Bootrec /fixmbr

   Bootrec /fixboot

   Bootrec /scanos

   Bootrec /rebuildbcd
   ```

It showed my C drive as windows and asked to add it as boot option .I said Y for yes and it Booted into windows 8.1 successfully.

Comment: Glad everything worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command `sudo os-prober`

If the output shows you Windows then you are in safe. So From your booted Ubuntu system, use the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should help.

If the problem still then from the  windows recovery console:

```
bootrec / fixmbr
```

Then

```
bootrec / fixboot
```

then update-grub again from your Ubuntu

Comment: os-prober shows this:/dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi

Comment: Ok then from your Ubuntu run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: nope. still windows cant start.....I edited the question have a look at pls.

Comment: @Saurabh you have messed your Windows booting when you use the EasyBCD. So your problem appears from Windows itself not from GRUB. So I think you have to run windows recovery and fixboot

Comment: will recovery wipe my PC?I dont know fixboot

Comment: @Saurabh No it will not, It'll just fix your booting and MBR. Anyway I think you should ask some Windows expert to be sure of how to solve your problem. But I'm sure those commands will help.

Comment: show some help i.e link(And thank you so much)

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-system/unable-to-boot-win8-error-0xc0000098-the-boot/7e3493cd-a5e4-44a8-9b92-b4a8b1bd33fe

Comment: https://lebgeeks.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=13673

Comment: how to access windows  recovery console?

Comment: I think you need to boot into either Windows or a recovery CD to get to the recovery console. I wish I knew another way in, but I don't.